# How Do I Turn Google Ads For My Android Application?

Tags: android, google-play, google-ads-api

Our company application is published on google play store, but when I go to our adwords account and when Im trying to start campaign for it the field where Im supposed to enter application name is giving me no results like the app didnt exist yet Im able to find it through search in google store here it is:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.companyname.New_Pneumatig

How do I start ads for it?

Comment: Just wait for several days

Answer (score 0):

Waiting 24 hours did helped, app appeard and I was able to start ads for it!